# Salesforce apex Installation in netbeans or eclipse

Tags: ide

I am newbie on both sales force and apex how can i install Apex in windows and how can I run them... can any one help me please
Salesforce apex Installation in eclipse in windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In given link step by step instruction to setup eclipse force.com IDE in windows/osx are given. Force.com IDE still do not support netbeans. There is nothig "Salesforce Apex" it is know as "Force.com IDE".

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation_for_Eclipse_3.6

To install FORCE.COM IDE download eclipse and run it and go to Help > 'install new software' and enterhttp://www.adnsandbox.com/tools/ide/install/ in "work with" labeled text box and follow instructions.

Comment: No, Salesforce has no support for netbeans. I know developer from java side loves netbeans more than eclipse :)